# "AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope" when trying to access element of vector of pointers

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

Why the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef struct Number {
    int number = 15;
} Number;

int main() {
    std::vector<Number*> nums(5);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
        Number num;
        nums[i] = &num;
    }

    std::cout << nums[1]->number << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

trigger "AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope", but when i comment line 15: `std::cout << nums[5]->number << "\n";` it compiles well? How to fix it?

Compile command: `clang++ main.cpp -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wsign-compare -g -o debug_solution && ./debug_solution`

Comment: Take your C++ textbook and learn about the `new` operator. And about `std::shared_ptr`, while you're at it.

Comment: You are saving into the vector the address of `num`: what is the lifetime of `num`?

Comment: Unrelated: In C++ you define structs as `struct Number { ... };`

Comment: Note: If you instead print out the addresses stored in `nums`, odds are high that you'd find they are all the same. Should give you a few hints about what's gone wrong here.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Im on my way to become a c++ lord.

Comment: No problem, @laser_sex_machine, future C++ Lord!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are storing a pointer to a value on the stack that goes out of scope and gets destroyed, leaving a dangling pointer.

```
std::vector<Number*> nums(5);
for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
    Number num;
    nums[i] = &num;
    // num goes out of scope here and num[i] has a dangling pointer
    //    to an invalid object
}

std::cout << nums[1]->number << "\n";
```

In this toy example, I see no reason to use pointers at all, and the fix would be just to use a `std::vector<Number>`:

```
std::vector<Number> nums(5);

// per comment by @user4581301
// this loop is not really needed, as the constuctor will
// default-construct the elements for you
for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
    Number num;
    nums[i] = num;
}

std::cout << nums[1].number << "\n";
```

If you really do need dynamic memory allocation on the heap, you should look at using an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Number>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Number>>` depending on if the object needs to be shared between multiple components.

Comment: In the no-pointers case there's no need for the loop at all. `std::vector<Number> nums(5);` created all of the required default-constructed `Number`s.

Comment: Very true, added note.

Comment: Big thanks! It's really just toy example, true code with same problem is about 300 lines (perfect hash realization).